# Spring Boot MVC/Thymeleaf and the 'replacement character'

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding, thymeleaf

we are developing an application which should display contents from a file. This file could contain any characters from `0x00` to `0xFF`. These values should be displayed too (we are using a fallback font for this purpose).

But somehow these "special characters" (like `0x00`) aren't displayed correctly. Something mapps these characters to the HTML replacement character � (U+FFFD).

So now we need a solution how we can deliver the "correct" value (which would be replaced with the fallback font) to the HTML page/front end.

My first thought was to deliver the hex values (not the strings) and convert these values on the front end by javascript.

Or are there smarter solutions? Maybe an configuration in Spring MVC/Thymeleaf?

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. What is the character encoding of the file? You can't read it as text without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `th:utext="#{unescaped text}">`